# Is there a way to cache a key value pair in ios watchkit extension app similar to images?

Tags: ios, caching, watchkit

In watchkit app, we can cache image files as given in this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Images.html

So I am asking for a way to cache key value pair similarly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that `NSUserDefaults` to be exactly what you're looking for. You can store simple key/values, though you should use the keychain for anything sensitive.

Here's the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: Thanks bgliham, but the data I am caching here is data coming from the assosciated ios app rather than app defaults. So is there a way to cache data sent by ios app to watch?

Comment: Not to cache it on the Watch itself, no.

Comment: I have an ios app which sends key value pairs to watch, so I want to cache those pairs on watchkit extension . How do I do this?

Comment: And I want both in memory and on disk caching. So is it possible to cache data on watchkit extension?

Answer (score 0):

`NSCache` might be something you are looking due to it flexibility. System will clear up cache once they need more space so that you don't need to worry too much on it.